# Which action to use: PUT or POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have resources in routes file:

```
resources :forwardings
```

And I need to add the action which will save settings to all items in collection.

The question is which method should I use to implement this one?

```
resources :forwardings do
  put 'save_all', :on => :collection
  # or
  post 'save_all', :on => :collection
end
```

Maybe I'm missing some details and I'd glad to hear out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both, it doesn't matter, both are 'good' for creating.

Read more here: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Really look into those answers, there are many explanations.

Answer (score 0):

PUT expects resource-ID in order to perform create/update operation and POST just create resource blindly. Or we can say that when posting data using POST then resource-ID is assigned by server after performing the requested operation so that using that resource-id further operation can be done. if we expect resource-id to be allocated from server side then we can use POST or if resource id is to be given by client then we can use PUT.